# FlutterSVG doesn't load SVG completely

Tags: flutter, svg, svgator

So I have this SVG file: https://svgshare.com/s/s9U that I'm trying to render with the help of the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package. But it seems like it is only rendering the border and not the text.

[image]

I made this SVG with [SVGator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI4u0.png) and exported it for the use of the web. I'm not sure what is wrong. Other SVGs that are not created on this website are working fine.

Below are the flutter logs:

```
I/flutter (10719): unhandled element style; Picture key: Svg loader
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is  because Color Inside the SVG is White And Scaffold Color is Also white That Why it's not showing Text That is use inside the image**:

I'm Try to Create An example for Better understanding:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("SVG Flutter"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/s9U.svg',
          height: 200.0,
          width: 200.0,
          allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]